# Android daily notification shows up multiple times at the wrong time

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to get an android notification to show up at noon every day. The notification seems to show up once whenever the device is started, then somewhat sporadically afterwards.

Here is my service:

```
public class myService extends Service {
public static final String TAG = "LocationLoggerServiceManager";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(TAG, "on onCreate");
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("App name")
            .setContentText("Notification")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify("main", 1, mBuilder.build());

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

and Receiver:

```
   public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String TAG = "LocationLoggerServiceManager";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast Received");
    handleMessage(context, intent);
}


private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, myService.class), 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(contentIntent);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , contentIntent);
}
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to set up my own notification / alarm class. The only way I found to manage it was to extend the Android calendar.

If you would like to try it this way see this link for a start:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

I have an example of this approach however i am at work, I can provide my code later if you need it!

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is that the system kills your Service to free up memory and since the superclass's `onStartCommand()` returns [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY), recreates it later, causing your notification to sporadically appear.

Really, if the Service's purpose is just to make a Notification consider moving that portion of code some sort of BroadcastReceiver or stop the Service after the Notification is created.

Comment: So get rid of the BroadcastReceiver all together?

Comment: @RyPope I'm guessing the `MyBroadcastReceiver` listens for boot time events. It is needed to set the noon "alarm". What is `myService` supposed to do other than make a notification?

Comment: I believe the service is what is called when for boot time events.

Comment: @RyPope Unlikely. Then the notification would appear during boot up, and not at noon. Anyways, what else does the Service do besides show the notification?

Comment: Well the notification does appear at startup, but i'll give it a go anyways

Comment: @RyPope My apologies, didn't catch that part of your question. Your manifest will tell you what exactly is set to receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast (considering it's a broadcast, it should be `MyBroadcastReceiver`). However, if the device is turned on after noon, the notification should appear - alarms set in the past execute as soon as they are registered.